# Does the variable of the current element in a Javascript for-each loop need defined outside the loop?

Tags: javascript

The W3Schools example for a JS for-each loop (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) is

```
var person = {fname:"John", lname:"Doe", age:25};

var text = "";
var x;
for (x in person) {
    text += person[x];
}
```

and I'm wondering if there's any particular reason why `x` is defined outside of the loop if it's only used inside the loop in that particular example, or if that's necessary condition for defining a for-each loop, and if so, why?

Comment: No, `for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {` works fine. Probably best to avoid w3schools as a primary resource.

Comment: No, it's not required.  The particular reason is probably *"because w3schools"*

Comment: Google question: JS for loops

Comment: @CodeWhisperer I did Google it, and was brought to W3Schools

Comment: I am sure there are other places that can show you another for loop, even on stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is(/was) an old convention, meant largely to indicate that `x` does not exist only inside the loop.

Declaring variables at the top of a function is not necessary and is variously encouraged/discouraged by different style tools. It can be convenient to group variable declarations in one place, but may increase the distance between declaration and use (generally considered a bad thing).

In JS, the [`var` declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) works at function-scope, so variables are hoisted to the top of the nearest function and live for the duration of the function. See:

```js
function foo() {  
  for (var i = 19; i > 0; --i) { 
    console.log(typeof i); // number
  }
  
  console.log(typeof i); // number
}

foo();
```

Because the variable is accessible throughout the function, it is declared at the start of the function (C used to require this).

ES6 has changed this with the [`let` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), which introduces the more common block-level scoping. With `let`, the variable is only available inside of the loop:

```
function foo() {  
  for (let i = 19; i > 0; --i) { 
    console.log(typeof i); // number
  }

  console.log(typeof i); // undefined
}
```